# Double negation "does not any"

Tags: grammaticality, negation, double-negation, negative-polarity-items

I understand that [*any*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/any?q=any) has negative connotations, as can be seen in the above link, but I need to say that there are no pages in a book. I've come up with the following sentence:

> That book does not have any pages.

Is this a correct way to say that there are no pages in that book? It seems to be a double negation, with *does not* and *any*, so that would seem to mean that the book *does* have pages. Should I use a different word to *any*?

Comment: How is *any* a negative?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That isn't double-negation, that's **single** negation. Double-negation would be this:

> That book does not have no pages.

Sentences like the above are correct in many languages and are used in many non-standard forms of English, but are not correct in standard English.

You may be confused by the word *any*, which is a [negative polarity item](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/npi.html). The word *any* is not itself a negative, but it is required in place of *no* or *some* when the main verb is negative.

Comment: You are right, 'any' confused me. I thought 'any' itself is negative and I cannot mix it with "doesn't/don't"...

Comment: Surely this would be correct in standard English if one means that the book has pages.

Comment: @Jez It would be formally and logically correct, but its use would require strong vocal or typographic emphasis on *no*. It is not a natural way of asserting that a book has *some* pages.

Comment: And?  That doesn't mean it's "not correct".

Comment: @StoneyB: Indeed, in some dialects the double-negative actually does mean to convey the negative: *"That book ain't got no pages,"* or in certain cases, *"That book don't got no pages."*

Comment: @Jez  There's correct and there's correct, even in Standard English. Correctness depends on register and discourse context. If you are denying a previously asserted lack of pages, it could be correct. In some contexts, as  Justin ᚅᚔᚈᚄᚒᚔ points out, this sentence would mean the exact opposite of what you look for it to mean. In others it would be unnatural and unidiomatic, which are also components of correctness.

Comment: I hadn't heard the term "negative polarity item"; it's interesting.  I think it may be worth noting that "any" has some senses in which it only works in the negative, and other senses in which it works in the positive but has different meaning: "He'll eat any kind of fish" [he'll eat all kinds], "He won't eat any kind of fish" [there's no kind he'll eat], "He'll eat just about any kind of fish" [a positive-only formulation; essentially all kinds], "He won't eat just any kind of fish" [a negative-only formulation; he'll eat some kinds--possibly many--but not all].